# Wix .NET 4.0 Framework Root Directory

Tags: installation, wix, wix3.5

For .NET 3.5 in Wix, I was able to use this [NETFRAMEWORK35INSTALLROOTDIR] to get the path to the 3.5 root directory, so I could do something like the following...
[NETFRAMEWORK35INSTALLROOTDIR]\aspnet_iapi.dll

I am trying to do something similar in but pointing to the .NET 4.0 directory.  I am trying to do wildcard mapping.  Here is the WIX Web Application Extension element.

```
<iis:WebApplicationExtension CheckPath="no"
    Script="yes"
    Executable="[NETFRAMEWORK40INSTALLROOTDIR]aspnet_isapi.dll"
    Verbs="GET,HEAD,POST DELETE PUT"/>
```

The problem is that in IIS 6 the wildcard path is always simply "aspnet_isapi.dll", so obviously the framework root variable isn't working.

Is there something I am doing wrong or is there another way to reliably get the .net 4.0 root directory?  If it matters, I am using WIX 3.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer lies in the documentation for the [WixNetFxExtension](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wixnetfxextension.htm):

> NETFRAMEWORK40FULLINSTALLROOTDIR
>
> Set to the installation directory for the .NET Framework 4.0 full
>   (%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0). This property is available
>   starting with WiX v3.5.
>
> NETFRAMEWORK40FULLINSTALLROOTDIR64
>
> Set to the installation directory for the 64-bit .NET Framework 4.0
>   full (%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0). This property is
>   available starting with WiX v3.5.

There are also separate properties for the client profile:

> NETFRAMEWORK40CLIENTINSTALLROOTDIR
>
> NETFRAMEWORK40CLIENTINSTALLROOTDIR64

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for that in the docs, but I couldn't find it for some reason.

Comment: I am using this property, but the output log that is generated, shows me that property is blank. What do I need to do to get a path for that ?

Comment: other than the namespace and the nuget package, make sure you add the PropertyRef
<PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK40CLIENTINSTALLROOTDIR64" />